# Downloading a music file instead of playing it in the browser

Tags: javascript, file, download

I'm trying to make a downloader on my website which starts downloading the selected files but the problem is it is a music file which just opens up in a new window and starts playing it.

The script is (don't worry about the id part it is for the next part):

```
function downloadsong(id){
    var url = ("/music/downloadablesongs/linkin-park/Minutes-to-Midnight/wake.mp3");
    window.open(url,'Download')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can configure the server that hosts the files, you should be able to manipulate the HTTP headers to include a "Content-Disposition" header. This will prompt the user agent (browser) to save the file, rather than allow it to automatically detect/interpret the content.

The basic format is:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name.ext
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the user's browser. Usually, plugins or built-in browser capabilities take over and play it instead of letting the browser download.

What you can do is to have the file carry no extension (ie. remove `.mp3`). That way, it won't be picked-up by plugins. The down side is additional work for the user, by having to add the extension manually.

Comment: yer but if the user is not that good with a computer he/she will not know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Other way is simply use the download attribute. I think is the simplest way.

```
<a href="/music/downloadablesongs/linkin-park/Minutes-to-Midnight/wake.mp3" download>
```

See more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp).